# Error al instalar librería xlsx en RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo instalado RStudio Versión 1.2.5033 con versión de R 3.6.2.

Intento instalar la librería xlsx usando

```
install.packages("xlsx")
```

pero me marca lo siguiente:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Luis Alberto/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
xlsx  0.6.1  0.6.2             FALSE

...
Rd warning: C:/Users/Luis 
...
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'xlsx':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error: loading failed
Ejecución interrumpida
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/Luis Alberto/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/xlsx'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xlsx’ had non-zero exit status
```

Y no me permite usar la librería

```
library(xlsx)
```

me dice

```
Error in library(xlsx) : there is no package called ‘xlsx’
```

Lo que quiero es guardar dataframes en un excel pero en diferentes pestañas.

Comment: Este suele ser un problema por que 1) No tienes instalado `JAVA`  o 2) No lo tienes en la misma arquitectura (32 o 64 bits) que `R`. Por empezar : 1) Verifica por la linea de comando `java -version` y si está instalado verifica que arquitectura es 2) en R ejecuta `sessionInfo()` para saber también la arquitectura. La última vez que tuve este mismo error, no recuerdo exactamente lo que hice, pero involucró, desinstalar todas las versiones de java e instalar `Java 8` y el `JDK` también.

Comment: Otra cosa es revisar la variable de entorno  `JAVA_HOME`, en `R`:  `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")`, debería existir y apuntar a la instalación correcta de `JAVA`

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es al instalar la librería *xlsx* sino uno de *rJava*. Podríamos indagar qué ocurre porque posiblemente sea un problema adicional con la instalación de Java en tu Sistema Operativo, pero una propuesta es usar esta otra librería soportada desde *tidyverse* que no tiene esas dependencias y es totalmente compatible para leer archivos Excel: [readxl](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/)

Así, para instalarlo, bastará con que instales directamente *tidyverse* o sino quieres instalarlo librerías adicionales bastará con lo siguiente:

```
install.packages("readxl")
```

Independientemente de si la instalas con todo el metapaquete *tidyverse* o con la línea anterior, deberás cargarla así:

```
library(readxl)
```

Y finalmente para leer un archivo:

```
xls_example <- readxl_example("datasets.xls")
read_excel(xls_example)
```